# Change values ​in rows x columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace, apply

I need help creating a function to change the value of certain rows in certain columns.

Considering the following dataframe:

```
serie = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
dataX = [0.1, 0.24, 0.21, 0.1, 0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.38, 0.49]
dataY = [0.1, 0.23, 0.21, 0.1, 0.27, 0.2, 0.2, 0.38, 0.49]
dataZ = [0.1, 0.26, 0.21, 0.1, 0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.49, 0.59]
dataW = [0.1, 0.23, 0.21, 0.1, 0.28, 0.2, 0.2, 0.49, 0.59]

my_dict = {'serie': serie, 
        'dataX': dataX, 
        'dataY': dataY, 
        'dataZ': dataW, 
        'dataW': dataZ}

df_serialized = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
```

I need to change the dataY and dataZ columns to zero whenever the value of the series column is zero.

What I already tried:

```
df_serialized[df_serialized.serie == 0][['dataY', 'dataZ']].apply(np.zeros)
```

returns the following error message:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df_serialized[df_serialized.serie == 0][['dataY', 'dataZ']].apply(np.zeros)
>
> 3 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py
>   in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args,
>   **kwds)    6485                          args=args,    6486                          kwds=kwds)
>   -> 6487         return op.get_result()    6488     6489     def applymap(self, func):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in
>   get_result(self)
>       149             return self.apply_raw()
>       150 
>   --> 151         return self.apply_standard()
>       152 
>       153     def apply_empty_result(self):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in
>   apply_standard(self)
>       255 
>       256         # compute the result using the series generator
>   --> 257         self.apply_series_generator()
>       258 
>       259         # wrap results
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in
>   apply_series_generator(self)
>       284             try:
>       285                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
>   --> 286                     results[i] = self.f(v)
>       287                     keys.append(v.name)
>       288             except Exception as e:
>
> TypeError: ("'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an
>   integer", 'occurred at index dataY')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df_serialized.loc[df_serialized.serie == 0, 'dataY'] = 0
df_serialized.loc[df_serialized.serie == 0, 'dataZ'] = 0
```

or at once

```py
df_serialized.loc[df_serialized.serie == 0, ['dataZ', 'dataY']] = 0
```